# spatial.exp on WinBUGS

Tags: geospatial, bayesian, winbugs, r2winbugs

I really hope this is not a stupid question, but I am trying to simulate a very simple spatial Bayesian model and I keep getting some sort of "incopmatible copy"  message on the WinBUGS window.

I am simulating data:

```
library(MASS)
library(spBayes)
library(fields)
library(MBA)
library(MASS)
library(R2WinBUGS)
set.seed(137)
n<-20
coords <- cbind(runif(n, 0, 1), runif(n, 0, 1))
phi<-0.25/0.5
sigma.sq<-0.0008
R<-exp(-phi*iDist(coords))

w<-mvrnorm(1,rep(0,n),sigma.sq*R)
x=coords[,1]
y=coords[,2]

z=0.031+w
data<-list("n","x","y","z")
vars2keep<-list("phi","tau","beta0","beta1")
inits<-function(){list(tau=0.001, phi=0.1, beta0=0.1,beta1=0.01)}

output<-bugs(
model.file="spatialexp_sim.txt",
data=data,
inits = inits,
parameters.to.save = vars2keep,
n.chains=2,
n.iter=1000,
n.burnin=500,
n.thin=10,
debug=TRUE,
DIC=TRUE
 )
```

And here is the model:

```
cat("

model{

 rho[1:n] ~ spatial.exp(mu[], x[], y[], tau, phi, 1)
  for (i in 1:n){mu[i]<-beta0}

 for (i in 1:n) {
   z[i] ~ nu[i]
   nu[i] <- rho[i] + beta1
 }

 beta0 ~ dflat()
 beta1 ~ dflat()      # Flat prior for the intercept
 tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)  # Conjugate inverse gamma on the precision
 phi ~ dunif(0.001, 0.8)     # Uniform prior on phi

 }",file="spatialexp_sim.txt"
)
```

Any clues why this thing is not working? I apologize if it is something really simple. 
Thanks a bunch!